# Binomial expansion manipulation

Tags: polynomials, summation, binomial-theorem

Can someone help me manipulate the following binomial expansion such that I can pull a factor of $z$ out of $$\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^j x^{k-j} \left( y^j - \sum_{i=0}^j \binom{j}{i} y^{j-i} z^i \right)$$

If you put this into Wolfram, every factor has a $z$ in it, but I can't figure out how to manipulate the above expression such that I can write $$z \left( \sum_{j=0}^k \cdots \right)$$

Comment: Hint: Split the inner sum into $i=0$ and $i=1,\ldots,j.$

Comment: There is even a closed form for the whole expression. What is $\sum_{i=0}^j \binom{j}{i} y^{j-i}  z^i$ ? Then, do what Reinhard Meier commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\;\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^j x^{k-j} \left( y^j - \sum_{i=0}^j \binom{j}{i} y^{j-i} z^i \right)\\
=&\;\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}  x^{k-j}(-y)^j  - \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j} (-1)^j x^{k-j}\sum_{i=0}^j \binom{j}{i} y^{j-i} z^i \\
=&\;(x-y)^k  - \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j} (-1)^j x^{k-j}(y+z)^j \\
=&\;(x-y)^k  - \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}  x^{k-j}(-y-z)^j \\
=&\;(x-y)^k  - (x-y-z)^k \\
\end{align}

If you want to pull out a factor of $z$,

\begin{align}
&\;(x-y)^k  - (x-y-z)^k \\
=&\;(x-y)^k -\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} ( x-y)^{k-j}(-z)^j \\
=&\;(x-y)^k - ( x-y)^{k}-\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j} ( x-y)^{k-j}(-z)^j \\
=&\;z\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j} ( x-y)^{k-j}(-z)^{j-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If the main focus is factoring out $z$ only, note the summand of the inner sum with $i=0$ is equal to $y^j$.

> So, $y^j$ cancels out and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^k& \binom{k}{j} (-1)^j x^{k-j} \left( y^j - \sum_{i=0}^j \binom{j}{i} y^{j-i} z^i \right)\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{j+1} x^{k-j}\sum_{i=1}^j \binom{j}{i} y^{j-i} z^i\\
> &=z\left(\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{j+1} x^{k-j}\sum_{i=1}^j \binom{j}{i} y^{j-i} z^{i-1}\right)\\
> &=zP(x,y,z)
> \end{align*}
>   with $P(x,y,z)$ a polynomial in $x,y$ and $z$.